# Why does Observable.Generate() throw System.StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, scheduler

I´m writing a C# (.NET 4.5) application that is used to aggregate time based events for reporting purposes. To make my query logic reusable for both realtime and historical data I make use of the Reactive Extensions (2.0) and their `IScheduler` infrastructure (`HistoricalScheduler` and friends).

For example, assume we create a list of events (sorted chronologically, but they may coincide!) whose only payload ist their timestamp and want to know their distribution across buffers of a fixed duration:

```cs
const int num = 100000;
const int dist = 10;

var events = new List<DateTimeOffset>();
var curr = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var gap = new Random();

var time = new HistoricalScheduler(curr);

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    events.Add(curr);
    curr += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(gap.Next(dist));
}

var stream = Observable.Generate<int, DateTimeOffset>(
    0,
    s => s < events.Count,
    s => s + 1,
    s => events[s],
    s => events[s],
    time);

stream.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(num), time)
    .Subscribe(l => Console.WriteLine(time.Now + ": " + l.Count));

time.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(num * dist));
```

Running this code results in a `System.StackOverflowException` with the following stack trace (it´s the last 3 lines all the way down):

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange<System.IDisposable>(ref System.IDisposable location1, System.IDisposable value) + 0x3d bytes    
System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable.Dispose() + 0x37 bytes    
System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem<System.DateTimeOffset>.Cancel() + 0x23 bytes    
...
System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Disposables.AnonymousDisposable.Dispose() + 0x4d bytes    
System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable.Dispose() + 0x4f bytes    
System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem<System.DateTimeOffset>.Cancel() + 0x23 bytes    
...
```

Ok, the problem seems to come from my use of `Observable.Generate()`, depending on the list size (`num`) and regardless of the choice of scheduler.

What am I doing wrong? Or more generally, what would be the preferred way to create an `IObservable` from an `IEnumerable` of events that provide their own timestamps?

Comment: How large can `num` be before you encounter this error? Also, if you single-step this in the debugger, what's the last line of code that executes before you see the error?

Comment: To me, the critical threshold seems to be at ~ `num = 51600` (in Release config, a little less in Debug config). The observable sequence seems to get completely created. I can hit breakpoints at the lamdba expressions for `Observable.Generate()`. The exception gets thrown after the last call to `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Understand, this is just a guess, but it looks suspiciously like the stream is trying to dispose of each element, and each element is trying to dispose the stream. You end up with what are essentially recursive calls to `Cancel` or `Dispose`, which blows your stack (default size of which is 1 megabyte). I'm not familiar enough with `Observable` to say why this is happening.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks a lot for your input, I think you pointed me into exactly the right direction. See below for a way that seems to work, at least for my immediate needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(update - realized I didn't provide an alternative: see at bottom of answer)

The problem is in how `Observable.Generate` works - it's used to unfold a [corecursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) (think recursion turned inside out) generator based on the arguments; if those arguments end up generating a *very* nested corecursive generator, you'll blow your stack.

From this point on, <strike>I'm speculating a lot (don't have the Rx source in front of me)</strike> (see below), but I'm willing to bet your definition ends up expanding into something like:

```
initial_state =>
generate_next(initial_state) => 
generate_next(generate_next(initial_state)) => 
generate_next(generate_next(generate_next(initial_state))) =>
generate_next(generate_next(generate_next(generate_next(initial_state)))) => ...
```

And on and on until your call stack gets big enough to overflow. At, say, a method signature + your int counter, that'd be something like 8-16 bytes per recursive call (more depending on how the state machine generator is implemented), so 60,000 sounds about right (1M / 16 ~ 62500 maximum depth)

EDIT: Pulled up the source - confirmed: the "Run" method of Generate looks like this - take note of the nested calls to `Generate`:

```
protected override IDisposable Run(
    IObserver<TResult> observer, 
    IDisposable cancel, 
    Action<IDisposable> setSink)
{
    if (this._timeSelectorA != null)
    {
        Generate<TState, TResult>.α α = 
                new Generate<TState, TResult>.α(
                     (Generate<TState, TResult>) this, 
                     observer, 
                     cancel);
        setSink(α);
        return α.Run();
    }
    if (this._timeSelectorR != null)
    {
        Generate<TState, TResult>.δ δ = 
               new Generate<TState, TResult>.δ(
                   (Generate<TState, TResult>) this, 
                   observer, 
                   cancel);
        setSink(δ);
        return δ.Run();
    }
    Generate<TState, TResult>._ _ = 
             new Generate<TState, TResult>._(
                  (Generate<TState, TResult>) this, 
                  observer, 
                  cancel);
    setSink(_);
    return _.Run();
}
```

EDIT: Derp, didn't offer any alternatives...here's one that might work:

(EDIT: fixed `Enumerable.Range`, so stream size won´t be multiplied by `chunkSize`)

```
const int num = 160000;
const int dist = 10;

var events = new List<DateTimeOffset>();
var curr = DateTimeOffset.Now;
var gap = new Random();
var time = new HistoricalScheduler(curr);

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    events.Add(curr);
    curr += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(gap.Next(dist));
}

    // Size too big? Fine, we'll chunk it up!
const int chunkSize = 10000;
var numberOfChunks = events.Count / chunkSize;

    // Generate a whole mess of streams based on start/end indices
var streams = 
    from chunkIndex in Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling((double)events.Count / chunkSize) - 1)
    let startIdx = chunkIndex * chunkSize
    let endIdx = Math.Min(events.Count, startIdx + chunkSize)
    select Observable.Generate<int, DateTimeOffset>(
        startIdx,
        s => s < endIdx,
        s => s + 1,
        s => events[s],
        s => events[s],
        time);

    // E pluribus streamum
var stream = Observable.Concat(streams);

stream.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(num), time)
    .Subscribe(l => Console.WriteLine(time.Now + ": " + l.Count));

time.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(num * dist));
```

Comment: Thanks, that´s perfect! Also seems to be more efficient than my own workaround. I had to fix a small error in your arithmetic, though (see edit). I still don´t quite see why the recursive implementation is needed inside RX. After all, it seems to work with RX v1.0 (well beyond a size of 60,000). Still, nice investigation, clever solution. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Heh - I'm actually impressed I only had *one* math error... ;)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I´ve taken a different factory method that doesn´t require lamdba expressions as state transitions and now I don´t see any stack overflows anymore. I´m not yet sure if this would qualify as a correct answer to my question, but it works and I thought I´d share it here:

```cs
var stream = Observable.Create<DateTimeOffset>(o =>
    {
        foreach (var e in events)
        {
            time.Schedule(e, () => o.OnNext(e));
        }

        time.Schedule(events[events.Count - 1], () => o.OnCompleted());

        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
```

Manually scheduling the events before (!) returning the subscription seems awkward to me, but in this case it can be done inside the lambda expression.

If there is anything wrong about this approach, please correct me. Also, I´d still be happy to hear what implicit assumptions by `System.Reactive` I have violated with my original code.

(Oh my, I should have checked that earlier: with RX v1.0, the original `Observable.Generate()` does in fact seem to work!)