# Using RxJS's `generate` to create a non-drifiting timer, how to use the `scheduler`?

Tags: timer, rxjs, scheduler, rxjs6

In search for a timer - triggered every minute, on the minute - that doesn't drift, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838113/observable-timer-how-to-avoid-timer-drift) solution. However I'm having difficulties understanding how to use / construct the last parameter `scheduler?: SchedulerLike`.

```
const noDrift = generate(
  0,
  _ => true, // start condition
  i => ++i,  // iterate
  i => i,    // result selector
  i =>  ...  // scheduler?: SchedulerLike; every minute on the minute, but how?
);

noDrift.subscribe(() => {
  // action
});
```

original solution that drifts:

```
const date = new Date();

// calculate how many ms are left till the full minute is reached
const tillNextFullMinute = (60 - date.getSeconds()) * 1000 - date.getMilliseconds();

// start on the next full minute, then just every minute
this.currentTime = timer(tillNextFullMinute, 60 * 1000);
this.currentTime.subscribe(value => {
  // action
});
```

Comment: Why don't use just use `interval` which is implemented internally with a single `setInterval` call? Are you saying `setInterval` drifts?

Comment: If I understand things correctly, yes `setInteval` can drift see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/985692/1378051

Comment: That question is nine years old. You might want to check the behaviour of current implementations - which might or might not be better behaved.